# Android 4.3 ble back to back connection

Tags: android, connection, profile, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using android 4.3 sdk for ble connection.  In my app Phone acts as client and  connect request is sent Gatt server: using `connectGatt()` method and `BluetoothGatt` is initialized.

```
mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
```

Gatt Service's are discovered, "Find Me" profile works, Battery and Tx power is read.
Now i connect to second device, using the same `connectGatt()` method and initialize `BluetoothGatt` for second device.  Gatt services of second device are discovered and `"Find Me"` profile works for second device.

Whenever i need Find Me Profile of two devices, i need to send connect request to device, get Gatt services and then use Finde Me Profile.

Connection is not established with Gatt server everytime and i am not able to connect to two devices and use "Find Me" Profile.

Has any one tried to connect two devices and use "Find Me" profile or sending connection request to Gatt server multiple times has worked for any one.

Comment: You got something for this?

Answer (score 0):

See Google's BLE sample, you should create a service and avoid connecting "multiple times".